# Error while using single and double qoutes in python3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, cut

I am getting a EOL Error in python while using the os.system() function.
Following is the code line generating error :

```
os.system("cat subdomains.txt | cut -d'"' -f1 ")
```

Basically I am trying to modify ouutput string using the delimeter  [ " ] (A Double quote)

Comment: If you need to write a `"` inside a `"`-quoted string, write it as ```\"```

Comment: I tried that but the thing is that we cannot the cut command syntax ! , Can you write the above command using your solution ?

Comment: ```"cat subdomains.txt | cut -d'\"' -f1 "```

Comment: Thanks alot man !! It Worked !! how do i upvote ya answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to write a `"` inside a `"`-quoted string, you can write it as `\"`

```
"cat subdomains.txt | cut -d'\"' -f1 "
```